# Data not getting fetched through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page index.php that has the following code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="assignto" id="assignid">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="selective">Selective</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="displaydata"></div>

<div class="form-group" id="recruiter"></div>
```

Ajax code used on this page is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#assignid').change(function(){

        var assignid_id = $('#assignid').val();
        console.log($('#assignid'))
        if(assignid_id != 0)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'a_fetchrecruiter_skill.php',
                data:{id:assignid_id},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#displaydata').html(returndata);
                    console.log(returndata)
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#areaid').change(function(){

        var areaid_id = $('#areaid').val();
        console.log($('#areaid'))
        if(areaid_id != 0)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'a_fetchrecruiter.php',
                data:{id:areaid_id},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#recruiter').html(returndata);
                    console.log(returndata)
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

When the value is selected from first dropdown the second dropdown gets fetched from a_fetchrecruiter_skill.php page with proper values.

Code on a_fetchrecruiter_skill.php page is

```
if($assignid_id=='selective')
    { ?>

        <label for="input01" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px; margin-top: -8px;">Select area </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?php
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM recruiter_skill group by recruiter_skill";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                ?>
                <select name="assignto" class="form-control" id="areaid">
                <?php
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                        {?>
                            <option value="">Choose</option>
                            <?php 
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                    {?>
                                        <option value="<? echo $row['recruiter_skill'];?>"><? echo $row['recruiter_skill'];?></option>
                                    <?}
                        }
                    else
                        {?>
                            <option value="">No value available</option>
                      <?}?>
                </select>
            </div>
    <?}
?>
```

Now the issue is that when the user selects value from second dropdown then the values should get displayed from a_fetchrecruiter.php page, but the second ajax is not working. it is not carrying the values to a_fetchrecruiter.php I tried to print data through console.log but nothing appears there.Can anyone plz point out the error

Comment: You are not echoing the html data in a_fetchrecruiter_skill.php.

Comment: You have to add semicolons after your `console.log(...)` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing lazy loading of content. Whenever the content is loaded dynamically you need to bind the event to the child with respect to already existing parent.

**For example:**

`$('#areaid').change(function(){`

should change to

`$('body').on('change', '#areaid', function()`{

Answer (score 0):

The element with #areid does not exist after page is loaded and therefore the `change` event doesn't fire.

You have to use jquery's `delegate` function:
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$('#displaydata').delegate('#areaid','change', function(){

    var areaid_id = $('#areaid').val();
    console.log($('#areaid'))
    if(areaid_id != 0)
    {

        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'a_fetchrecruiter.php',
            data:{id:areaid_id},
            cache:false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $('#recruiter').html(returndata);
                console.log(returndata)
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind `change` event to `#areaid` after you have loaded it from ajax, not on `$(document).load`